# Call Dlang function in struct with Python ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, d

I have a `.so` (written in Dlang) which has a struct as below

```
struct A
{
    static A* load(string folder)
    { }
}
```

I am trying to consume the `.so` in Python.  I am not sure how can i call the function which is present inside the structure.

My python code is below

```
from ctypes import *


class A(Structure):
     _fields_ = [
        ("load", CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p,c_char_p))
    
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    so_path = "./libmycode.so"
    lib = CDLL(so_path)
    /* not sure how to call the load method */
```

I want to call the functions available in `.so` which is present inside the struct from python code.

Comment: Not familiar with DLang, but `ctypes` needs a C calling convention and can only support POD (plain old data) C types like `int`, `float`, `double`, `char`, raw pointers and `struct` collections of those types.  If DLang has similar support like C++ for the like of `extern "C"` or some way to provide metadata on how to marshal a `string` like C# you should be able to do it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thank you. i will see if there is a extern C defined. Thanks for your input

Comment: I added a `d` tag to see if some D expert can judge your D code for being called from C looks right.

Answer (score 1):

The ctypes module is designed to access a C module. So, you should define a C compatible structure and implement a C compatible function that calls your `A.load()` and converts arguments and return value.

This is an example for that, assuming the `A` has a string member.

```
import std.string;
import std.conv;
import core.stdc.stdlib;
import core.stdc.string;

struct A
{
    string s;
    static A* load(string s) {
        auto a = new A;
        a.s = s ~ s;
        return a;
    }
};

struct AForC
{
    char* s;
};

extern (C) AForC* loadAForC(const char* s)
{
    auto a = A.load(to!string(s));
    auto aForC = cast(AForC*)malloc(AForC.sizeof);
    if (aForC) {
        aForC.s = strdup(a.s.toStringz());
    }
    return aForC;
}
```

Now you can call `loadAForC()` in Python using the ctypes.

As a side note, a static member function of a struct in D or C++ is not stored inside a struct instance. So you should not define it in the `_fields_` in Python.